# Multiplication that has different text color for each row

Tags: php

I have only gone as far as creating the multiplication table itself, but I couldn't think of a way to change the text color for each row, I am new to php and I have tried searching everywhere but all I found was to change the background color for each row, not the texts...any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
function multiplication_table($rows, $cols){
                echo "<table width =\"500\" height=\"500\" border=\"50\">";
                    for ($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++){
                        echo'<tr>';
                    for ($col = 1; $col <= $cols; $col++)
                        echo '<td align = "center">' .$col*$row.'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }   
                echo"</table>";
            }
```

If you have a different set of codes from the one I posted above please educate me! I will try my best to understand everything.

Comment: Welcome! @newbie look the problem here basically is you have `$row` and `$cols` as parameters in the function this means you are already carrying some values within them when calling the function but inside the function you are reinitializing the same variables as `$row=1` and `$cols=1` which chages there existing values and as a result `for` loop fails.

Comment: @KunalRaut hello! they two are different, my parameters were $rows and $cols, meanwhile the variables inside my for loop are $row and $col, i haven't encountered any problem regarding the loops, just that i couldn't change the font color for each row :(

Comment: Ohh i'm sorry i misunderstood it.

Comment: To just change the font color use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add `background color` to row:

```
function multiplication_table($rows, $cols){
            echo "<table width =\"500\" height=\"500\" border=\"50\">";
                for ($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++){
                    // Generate Random Color
                    $color = "#".substr(md5(rand()), 0, 6);
                    // Apply color to row
                    echo'<tr style="background-color:'.$color.'">';
                for ($col = 1; $col <= $cols; $col++)
                    echo '<td align = "center">' .$col*$row.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }   
            echo"</table>";
        }
```

Comment: hello! thanks for the help! but i was looking to change the font color for each row, not the background color of the row, i have thought several ways but i just couldn't :(

Comment: just simply change the `background-color` to `font-color`

Comment: hello! thank you so much! your solution solved it for me! i only changed it a little, as font-color didn't work somehow..i did '<tr style="color:'.$color.'">'; instead and it worked!! you are a life saver!!

Answer (score 0):

you must add class for any rows and set color for this class

```
function multiplication_table($rows, $cols){
                echo "<table width =\"500\" height=\"500\" border=\"50\">";
                    for ($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++){
                        echo'<tr class="row'+$row+'">';
                    for ($col = 1; $col <= $cols; $col++)
                        echo '<td align = "center">' .$col*$row.'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }   
                echo"</table>";
            }
```

and set color in css for example

```
.row1 , .row1 td 
{
   background:red;
}
```

Comment: doesn't that change the color of the background color of the row? im looking to change font color for each row, like row 1's texts are green, row 2's text color is red.. etc.. depending on how many rows the user will input..